# Creating a new column from existing column with different values in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame with the months June, May, July with various values. I am trying to create new columns for each month with new values. If the value is greater than or equal to 100 I would like it to be changed to 100 and in below 100 keep the value. Here is the df:

```
June <- c(100,50,200)
May <- c(250, 100, 20)
July <- c(20, 300, 20)

df <- data.frame(June, May, July)
```

and my goal is to have the df look like this:

```
June <- c(100,50,200)
May <- c(250, 100, 20)
July <- c(20, 300, 20)
June_new <- c(100,50,100)
May_new <- c(100,100,20)
July_new <- c(20,100,20)

df2 <- data.frame(June, May, July,June_new, May_new, July_new)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, using simple `ifelse` to check condition and add columns to df itself.

```
df$new_June <- ifelse(df$June>=100, 100, df$June)
df$new_May <- ifelse(df$May>=100, 100, df$May)
df$new_July <- ifelse(df$July>=100, 100, df$July)
```

BEFORE df value:

```
> df
  June May July
1  100 250   20
2   50 100  300
3  200  20   20
```

After running commands df value:

```
df$new_June <- ifelse(df$June>=100, 100, df$June)
df$new_May <- ifelse(df$May>=100, 100, df$May)
df$new_July <- ifelse(df$July>=100, 100, df$July)
df

  June May July new_June new_May new_July
1  100 250   20      100     100       20
2   50 100  300       50     100      100
3  200  20   20      100      20       20
>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!!

Comment: @Jake, glad that it helped you, cheers keep learning and keep sharing.